# How to make Nginx reverse proxy wait until upstream comes online

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a server app that listens on a UNIX socket, and Nginx serving as a reverse proxy.

Now I want Nginx to wait until my app comes online when e.g. I deploy an update and restart it, without returning any errors to the clients.

This is what I have in my Nginx config:

```
location / {
#   proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/MyApp.sock;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    proxy_connect_timeout 60;
    proxy_send_timeout 60;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
}
```

However, whenever my app is down Nginx returns `502 Bad Gateway` *immediately*. Apparently none of the `proxy_*_timeout` settings help.

Same happens with a local TCP socket. With UNIX sockets, when I shut down the app I make sure the socket file is deleted, so that Nginx can see there's no app running.

How can I tell it to actually wait for a certain period of time until the socket becomes available?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the core nginx has such a functionality. However something similar can be achieved using the [nginx-lua-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module). Even if using that module isn't applicable for you, I'll post the working example here just in case it would help someone else.

```
error_page 502 = @error_502;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    ...
}
location = /heartbeat {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
location @error_502 {
    rewrite_by_lua_block {
        local timeout = 10
        local uri = ngx.var.uri
        local args = ngx.var.args
        local res = { status = 0 }
        while timeout > 0 do
            ngx.sleep(1)
            res = ngx.location.capture("/heartbeat")
            if res.status == 200 then break end
            timeout = timeout - 1
        end
        if res.status == 200 then
            ngx.exec(uri, args)
        end
    }
    access_by_lua_block {
        ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
        ngx.say("I'd waited too long... exiting.")
        ngx.exit(ngx.OK)
    }
}
```

This code should be quite straight to require any additional comments. The [`ngx.sleep`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxsleep) used here is a non-blocking one and takes its parameter in a microseconds granularity. Your app should be able to process the `/heartbeat` route in order to use this (probably consuming as little processing time as possible). I'm sure this can be adapted to use the UNIX socket too (maybe you'd need to move your upstream definition to the separate `upstream` block).

**Important note.** Since this solution relies on [`ngx.location.capture`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture) for making subrequests, it is incompatible with the HTTP/2 protocol because of [this](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/1195#issuecomment-346410275) limitation (read the whole discussion to find out possible workarounds if needed).

Answer (score 0):

I would not call it solution, but there is a way to achieve this with a `resolver`. You need a DNS for that, `docker` will bring one, but in your case you need to setup on our own on your server.

```
server
{
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=120s; #DNS-IP
resolver_timeout 60; # Timeout for resolver response
}
location / {
  set $upstream_service URI; #URI= DNS-Name:Port
  proxy_pass http://$upstream_service;
}
```

So nginx can't check availability of the service and ask the resolver. The resolvers answer is awaited up to its timeout. If no answer in timeout time: 502, if service comes back in this period it will answer and nginx will respond with 200.

But I have no clue if it's working with a sock..

Comment: I think to make this work the resolver response TTL should be less than the timeout, e.g. `valid=15s`. If it is, it should be possible to do something like that: 1) stop DNS; 2) wait 15 seconds to ensure the nginx resolver cache is get emptied; 3) update the web app; 4) start DNS. It may be an option if using the third party modules is impossible for some reason, however I don't think this can be adapted to work with UNIX sockets contrary to lua-nginx-module solution.

Comment: No need. Nginx is waiting for the resolver every time he can't reach the target. Working just out of the box, reboot service and go on. DNS may remain untouched. But like written: This is a solution if someone using Docker or is running a DNS anyways, even if it is not suitable for him it might be a solution for someone else..